# Which commentary on the MMK should be studied first?

Tags: nagarjuna

I am currently casually reading various things, and Ocean of Reasoning is one of those things. I've began to feel that I should pick a challenging reading to focus on, but I'm thinking I might want to read Ornament of Reason before Ocean of Reasoning.

Is one or the other traditionally studied first? Or is there some other commentary before these that I should study? I am already well acquainted with the Mūlamadhyamakakārikā itself.

Comment: may want to spell out MMK?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it depends on which lineage you draw your water from. Ocean of Reasoning is a Gelug text, as is Ornament of Reason (I think?), while in Kagyu they study Madhyamakavatara, a relatively early commentary by Candrakirti, with subcommentary by Jamgon Mipham.

Comment: Interesting point. I honestly have a really hard time keeping track of names of things in general let alone which lineage believes this or that. I kind of just soak in as much as I can from anywhere I can. Are you aware of an English translation of the Madhyamakavatara? I believe I looked for one and could only find a German translation or something like that.

Comment: @JoeMcDonagh, http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Middle-Way-Chandrakirtis-Madhyamakavatara/dp/1590300092/

Comment: 11 bucks for a used hardcover, on its way now. I guess for that reason I will read this one first. Still curious if there is a clear progression in traditional teaching. Thanks!!!!